How can I display datalabels after chart draw - Chart.js
I want to display datalabels after all of the chart animation completed.
But datalabels are already shown before the chart animation ended in my code.
Additionally, I'm not sure that my code is right for making chart reverse animated and adding text in the center of doughnut.
I use Chart.js 3.3.2 version.
And this is my code.
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var data = {
          labels: ['a','b'],
          datasets: [
            {
              data: [10, 0],
              backgroundColor: [
                "#D4CCC5",
                "#D4CCC5"
              ]
            }]
        };

    var pl= {id: "text",
    beforeDraw: function(chart, a, b) {
      var width = chart.width,
        height = chart.height,
        ctx = chart.ctx;

      ctx.restore();
      var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
      ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

      var text = "75%",
        textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
        textY = height / 1.5;

      ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
      ctx.save();
    }
  };
  var txt= [{
                id: this.canvasId + '_plugin',
                afterDraw: (chart) => { // Using arrow function here
                    chart.ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
                    chart.ctx.textBaseline = 'middle'
                    chart.ctx.textAlign = 'center'
                    chart.ctx.font = '17px Verdana'
                    // Using this.total here
                    chart.ctx.fillText('3',
                        chart.canvas.clientWidth / 2,
                        (chart.canvas.clientHeight / 2) + (titlePadding * 7 + 2 - bottomPadding))
                }
            }];

var promisedDeliveryChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  plugins:[txt,pl],
  data: data,
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    rotation: -90,
        circumference: 180,
        plugins:{datalabels:{
                    color: 'black',
                    anchor: 'center',
                    align:'center',
                    formatter: function (value, context) {
                            return context.chart.data.labels[
                                context.dataIndex]
        }
        }}
  }
});


setInterval(function() {
    data.datasets[0].data[1] = 10;
    data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[1] = "#F7464A";
        promisedDeliveryChart.update();
}, 1000);
</script>


To draw the datalabels after the animation is over, you have to use the
options.animation.onComplete callback. Set initially display: false in the datalabels options, and show them by setting display: true in onComplete. You may identify which animation has completed by reading the state of the chart instance. Here you have a version of your code that corrects some errors and contains some ideas on how to set things up differently, which you may or may not use.
